# Does SO_RCVTIMEO affect accept()?

Tags: c, sockets, posix

Does the `SO_RCVTIMEO` option affect `accept` (causing it to return `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK` if the timeout expires)? Is there any behavior specified by the standard? I can't find it in the documentation for `accept` or use of options:

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_10_16

Comment: I seem to recall the answer being no but I don't remember if the context was SO or something I read.  Stevens only mentions read, readv, recv, recvfrom and recvmsg as being affected.  It would seem if accept was affected by the option it would be documented somewhere because, well, it would be a useful in some instances.

Comment: Also, is it not the case that a connection will not go into the pending queue until the 3-way is already completed?  That would negate the point since you going to return with a new socket or not.

Comment: I was thinking of a blocking socket and the time `accept` spends blocked when there is no connection attempt.

Comment: I know but I thinking what a receive timeout would mean for accept.  There is nothing to receive at the app level and does the reception of the SYN/ACK really mean anything when there could be a significant delay between them?  A timer based on that doesn't seem to work which is why I don't think SO_RCVTIMEO is proper in this context.  Some other timer mechanism would be proper, namely something based on the semantics of there is nothing/something in the queue as opposed to a read buffer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

While on POSIX SO_RCVTIMEO is defined for "an input function", and SO_SNDTIMEO is defined for "an output function", I can'r find any definition for "input function" or "output function", so I'll just say they are read/receive and write/send at least.

In the specific case of Linux, SO_RCVTIMEO affects `accept()`, as can be seen by looking at [inet_csk_accept()](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.7.4/source/net/ipv4/inet_connection_sock.c#L473), and SO_SND_TIMEO affects `connect()`, as can be seen by looking at [tcp_sendmsg()](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.7.4/source/net/ipv4/tcp.c#L1221).

Comment: +1 and accepted, as there doesn't seem to be anything more to say on the matter except implementation specifics for other implementations.