# How to force a Windows Bluetooth Connect() call to timeout

Tags: c++, windows, bluetooth

Is there any way - Any way at all - to force the

```
BluetoothAuthenticateDevice( HWND hwndParent, HANDLE hRadio, BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO * pbtbi, PWSTR pszPasskey, ULONG ulPasskeyLength);
```

and the

```
connect(SOCKET s, const struct sockaddr FAR * name, int namelen);
```

function calls to timeout?

I have tried setting SO_RCVTIMEO and SO_SNDTIMEO to different values on the connect() socket to see if they affect the length of the function call, to no avail - and there is some discussion about whether they affect connect() anyway [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968121/does-so-rcvtimeo-affect-accept).

It appears the default timeout is about 5 seconds on connect() and can apparently be as [slow as 30-45 seconds on AuthenticateDevice](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b5aa5cb2-0c6a-4a40-a2c1-471458a86fce/set-timeout-or-abort-bluetoothauthenticatedevice?forum=xpwirelesssdk) - i have seen the auth/connect fail process take 80 seconds. However, if it hasn't connected in the first 1-2 seconds, it isn't going to - and until this gives up, our GUI can't display anything meaningful to the end user either way. The extra few seconds do matter.

Is it possible to actually enforce a timeout or is the only way to start it in a thread and kill the thread if it takes too long?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the socket as non-blocking before making the connect call?

```
long lFlag;
SOCKET btSocket;

   btSocket = socket(AF_BTH, SOCK_STREAM, BTHPROTO_RFCOMM);
   lFlag = 1;
   ioctlsocket(btSocket, FIONBIO, &lFlag);
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem - I need to cancel the connect() if it didn't work, not leave it to run in the background - I don't want it connecting in the background and then a re-try failing because it just connected...  Unless there's a way to cancel the non-blocking connect it if hasn't worked after (e.g.) 3 seconds?

Comment: Have you tried closing the socket on another thread while it's trying to connect?

Comment: No. The point of the question was to try and avoid having the background thread creating a second background thread... If that's the only way to do it, we'll do that, but then the answer to the question is "can't be done".